# How to do setVisibility in CardView?

Tags: android, list, android-cardview

How to do setVisibility in **CardView**? I would like to do setVisibility (GONE) for **CardView**. I don't want to do LinearLayout setVisibility (GONE). Programmatically. How to do this?

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cv_ingredient"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/cardMarginVertical"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/cardMarginHorizontal"
                    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/cardMarginHorizontal"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cardMarginVertical"
                    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                    app:cardElevation="5dp"
                    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
                    app:contentPadding="0dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/linear_ingredient"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                            <TextView
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Ingredients"
                                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                            <ListView
                                android:id="@+id/list_ingredient"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Linear layout is inside cardView?

Comment: is CradView inside CardView?

Comment: LinearLayout is inside CardView.

Comment: So you want to hide the cardview but keep it's child view?

Comment: yes, I want to set the whole cardview including linearlayout, textview, etc. I can set linearlayout visibility gone; textview is also gone. but cardview is blank. design is so bad. So I would like to set cardview visibility gone.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just do this:

```
CardView cv_ingredient = (CardView) findViewById(R.id.cv_ingredient);
cv_ingredient.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: How to call findviewbyid for cv_ingredient? Plz. :)

Comment: I try like your comment (normal views like textview etc.) No, I can't. CardView have no import. :(

Comment: Then why don't you just import it? Click Alt + Enter and import it

Comment: I do compile, and then Alt + Enter, no see import, like textview.

Comment: do you have this inside your dependencies in you application level build.gradle file compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'?

Comment: Yes. I have this compile in my gradle.

Comment: import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that man!, Because `CardView` is act as parentView of `LinearLayout` here. Visibility of parentView will **AFFECT** the childView also.

Answer (score 0):

If you set visibility of  parent to GONE then all of  child Views will also be GONE,  you cannot set linearlayout visible white cardview is gone. I suggest redesign your layout

Comment: yes, I want to set the whole cardview including linearlayout, textview, etc. I can set linearlayout visibility gone; textview is also gone. but cardview is blank. design is so bad. So I would like to set cardview visibility gone.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this property to your second CardView

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use card view inside linearLayout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cv_ingredient"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorWhite"
    app:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
    app:cardElevation="5dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    app:contentPadding="0dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/cardMarginVertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/cardMarginHorizontal"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/cardMarginHorizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/cardMarginVertical">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ingredients"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_ingredient"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

I used like this in my app, this xml also you can use...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_customer_details_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@color/gray_drawer">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cutomerDetails_textView_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textSize="10sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cutomerDetails_textView_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cutomerDetails_textView_date"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cutomerDetails_textView_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cutomerDetails_textView_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/callButtonImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cutomerDetails_textView_name"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:background="@color/transparent"
            android:src="@drawable/phone" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just click on invalidate cache/restart in Android studio IDE. It is an IDE error. After that you can able to import the `CardView class` in java file.

```
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;

CardView editProfileLayout = (CardView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardview_layout);
editProfileLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```